# MouseOver-Window in Primefaces Datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, css

I have a Primefaces Datatable and each column filled with a OutputLabel. When the String in this label has to many characters, the text is not visible.

[image]

I'm looking for a way, to show a MouseOver-window or hint to show the full text. What would be the most painless way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of primefaces are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use Primeface [Tooltip](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml) component.

```
<p:tooltip value="<CONTENT_OF_TOOLTIP>" for="<COMPONENT_ID_ON_WHICH_TOOLTIP_WILL_APPEAR>" />
```

Even though the IDs generated in Primefaces Datable inner components are different over iteration of List, if you put `p:tooltip` also in table as in below example, primefaces will also generated dynamic IDs to `p:tooltip` component also.

Example:

```
   <p:dataTable value="#{heroMBean.herosList}" var="h">
        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <h:outputText id="hname" value="#{h.name}"/>
            <p:tooltip for="hname" value="#{h.name}"></p:tooltip>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Universe">
            <h:outputText id="huniverse" value="#{h.universe}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```